# How can I allow the IP range xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ip

I want to whitelist the IP range xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy with `iptables`. I have already tested many variants without success, like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -s xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -d xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -d xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy -j ACCEPT
```

I hope someone can help me :-)

Comment: I think the first line should work, but, maybe, there are some other rules that override this one. Please post the output of `iptables -L INPUT -n`. You can try to INSERT 'this' rule onto the top of INPUT chain - `iptables -I INPUT -s xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy -j ACCEPT`.

Comment: That's the output from "iptables -L INPUT -n "                                                                             target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  -- xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy     0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  -- xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy     0.0.0.0/0
.....

Comment: Agree with @pa4080, what you have shown should work, so something else is maybe overriding. Myself, I much much prefer `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` . Why? because it also shows the packet (and byte) counters making it easier trace the path that packets took and the network interfaces involved.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start

clear existing chains

```
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables --delete-chain
```

allow loopback

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Optional: allow all ICMP

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

allow established connections

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

then rule for all incoming traffic from `xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy`

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -s xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy -j ACCEPT
```

deny all accept above rules

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

default policies

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

save

```
sudo service iptables save
```

Try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *whitelist* that prefix, I assume you have a rule that matches a wider range (probably 0.0.0.0/0) that rejects all traffic. Are you sure that rule does not appear *before* any of your whitelisting? What is the output of `iptables --line-numbers --list -n`?

Comment: Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy      0.0.0.0/0
2    ACCEPT     all  --  xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy     0.0.0.0/0
...

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            IPv4IP from my local network

Comment: @f31ix_0r1g1na1: Could you please edit your question, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: `
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)`
`num  target     prot opt source               destination`
`1    ACCEPT     all  --  xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy      0.0.0.0/0`
`2    ACCEPT     all  --  xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy     0.0.0.0/0`
`3    ACCEPT     all  --  xxx.xx.xxx.x/yy      0.0.0.0/0`
`...[and more]`

`Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)`
`num  target     prot opt source               destination`

`Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)`
`num  target     prot opt source               destination`
`1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            [My local Ip Adress]`

Comment: please format properly.